# Python multiprocessing : The object reference of a Manager.dict() value is changing when iterated over [Not Solved]

Tags: python, dictionary, object, multiprocessing

Here is a simple way to describe my problem:

```
From multiprocessing import Manager 

class myObject():
    #Do stuff


manager = Manager() 
dictio = manager.dict()


dictio[(1)] = myObject() 
print (dictio[(1)])

dictio[(2)] = myObject() 
print (dictio[(2)])


for key,value in dictio.items():    
    print (value)    
    print (dictio[key])

print (dictio[(1)])
print (dictio[(2)])

exit()
```

Result of prints :

> print ( dictio [(1)] )
> object at **0x7f1dca56c850**

> print ( dictio [(2)] )
> object at **0x7f1dca56c880**

> print ( dictio [key] )
> object at **0x7f1dcac53af0**
> object at **0x7f1dca56c130**

> print ( value )
> object at **0x7f1dca56c550**
> object at **0x7f1dca56c550**

> print ( dictio [(1)] )
> object at **0x7f1dca56c850**

> print ( dictio [(2)] )
> object at **0x7f1dca56c880**

Why the object reference of print (dictio[(1)]) and print (dictio[(2)]) are differentes from print (value) and print (dictio[key]) in loop ?

And What can i do to keep the same reference when iterating over a proxydict ?

I have tried several things and it get me to this point where i am stuck.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Don't name your class `object`, that's the built-in root class.

Comment: What is `Manager`?

Comment: I edited my post. Manager came from multiprocessing. It is a way to get a proxydict and share it between process

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a simpler version of your program:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager

class myObject():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    dictio = manager.dict()


    obj1a = myObject()
    dictio[(1)] = obj1a
    obj1b = dictio[(1)]
    print(obj1a, obj1b, obj1a is obj1b)
```

Prints:

```None
<__main__.myObject object at 0x0000021410DF1370> <__main__.myObject object at 0x0000021410F5B9D0> False
```

When you create a `Manager` instance, a new process is created and any managed objects you create exist in the address space. So when you assign `dictio[(1)] = obj1a`, the object `obj1a` must be sent over to the manager's address space by serializing it, sending it and de-serializing it (done with `pickle`). Likewise, when you reference the dictionary entry with `obj1b = dictio[(1)]`, the instance in the manager's address space must now be sent back again by using `pickle`. When it arrives back in the new address space it is no longer the same object `obj1a` that you started out with and will therefore have a different address than `obj1a`.

Now lets look at the following code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager

class myObject():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    dictio = manager.dict()


    dictio[(1)] = myObject()
    dictio[(2)] = myObject()
    print(dictio[(1)]) # statement 1
    print(dictio[(2)]) # statement 2
    print(dictio[(1)], dictio[(2)]) # statement 3
```

Prints:

```None
<__main__.myObject object at 0x0000020A5B96AA00>
<__main__.myObject object at 0x0000020A5B96AA00>
<__main__.myObject object at 0x0000020A5B96AA00> <__main__.myObject object at 0x0000020A5B96A9D0>
```

When statement 1 is executed the manager's copy of the first object is sent pack to the main process for printing there. It occupies a certain address. But by time you get to statement 2, it has been garbage collected (technically, it is not garbage collection that is occurring but rather the object's reference count going to zero; actual garbage collection is used to detect circular references) and so when statement 2 is executed the second object arrives at the main process and just happens to occupy the same address as the first, garbage-collected object. But when statement 3 is executed, garbage collection doesn't occur until after the statement is executed and so the two copied objects must exist at the same time and cannot occupy the same address.

Now let's modify the previous program slightly to prevent the first object from having its reference count going down to 0 and being reclaimed by assigning it to some variable:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager

class myObject():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    dictio = manager.dict()


    dictio[(1)] = myObject()
    dictio[(2)] = myObject()
    obj1 = dictio[(1)]
    print(obj1) # statement 1
    print(dictio[(2)]) # statement 2
```

Prints:

```None
<__main__.myObject object at 0x000001EFAD66E9D0>
<__main__.myObject object at 0x000001EFAD66E9A0>
```

Now you can see that both copies, which exist at the same time, must be assigned unique addresses.